# Comparing floating point numbers with tolerance fails assertion

Tags: scala, floating-point, assert, scalatest

I am using ScalaTest (3.0.4), and can't get any examples to work that I've found of comparing floating point numbers with a tolerance. Here's what I have:

```
import org.scalatest.{MustMatchers, WordSpec}

class DetectionClusteringSpec extends WordSpec with MustMatchers {

    "EmbeddingsGroup.vecdist" should {
        "correctly compute vector distance" in {
            val dist = EmbeddingsGroup.vecdist(TestDetections.emb1,TestDetections.emb4)
            // Note: The above method returns a Float. 

            dist mustBe 3.058 +- 0.1
        }
    }
```

The above compiles, but when I run the test, I get the following failure:

```
3.0579379 was not equal to 3.058 +- 0.1
Expected :3.058 +- 0.1
Actual   :3.0579379
```

I also tied the following assertion instead:

```
assert(dist === 3.058)
```

However, that does not work either, and gives the following failure:

```
3.0579379 did not equal 3.058
Expected :3.058
Actual   :3.0579379
```

I've read numerous examples of comparing floating point numbers with both of the above syntaxes, and it seems like they should work. My first example is straight from [the documentation](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/org/scalatest/MustMatchers.html#checkingNumbersAgainstARange).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since `dist` is a `Float` whilst other arguments are `Double`s try converting `dist` to `Double` like so

```
dist.toDouble mustBe 3.058D +- 0.1
```

or make other arguments floats like so

```
dist mustBe 3.058f +- 0.1f
```

Possibly related to [Comparison matchers fail on mixed numeric types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56589516/comparison-matchers-fail-on-mixed-numeric-types)