# Comparison matchers fail on mixed numeric types

Tags: scala, scalatest, matcher, comparison-operators

In vanilla Scala the following assertions pass

```
assert(1D > 0F)
assert(1F > 0)
assert(1L > 0)
assert(1 > 0.toShort)
assert(1.toShort > 0.toChar)
```

however similar matchers in ScalaTest [fail](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/349)

```
1D shouldBe > (0F)
1F shouldBe > (0)
1L shouldBe > (0)
1 shouldBe > (0.toShort)
1.toShort shouldBe > (0.toChar)
```

A workaround is to make both sides the same type, for example

```
1D shouldBe > (0D)
```

Why does it work in Scala, but not in Scalatest, or what is it about the signature of [`>`](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/9e127207941836b19490c6cfacf9087e2c8ece89/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/Matchers.scala#L2753)

```
def >[T : Ordering] (right: T): ResultOfGreaterThanComparison[T]
```

that makes it fail?

Comment: Interestingly, `1D should be > 0D` works while `1D should be > 0F` does not compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vanilla Scala works due to automatic type conversion i.e. `0F` is cast to `0D` which is a common practise in many languages.

More interesting question is why `shouldBe` does not work. De-sugaring the implicits yields

```
new AnyShouldWrapper[Double](leftSideValue = 1D,
                             pos = ???,
                             prettifier = ???)
  .shouldBe(new ResultOfGreaterThanComparison[Double](right = 0D))

new AnyShouldWrapper[Double](leftSideValue = 1D,
                             pos = ???,
                             prettifier = ???)
  .shouldBe(new ResultOfGreaterThanComparison[Float](right = 0F))
```

which leads to overloaded implementations of `shouldBe`. The former case goes [here](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/release-3.0.5/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/Matchers.scala#L6899) and the latter [here](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/release-3.0.5/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/Matchers.scala#L6860).

After looking at the source code, it seems that the only reason `1D shouldBe > (0F)` actually compiles is to support array comparison with `shouldBe` keyword.